# Error manejando rebotes con interrupciones

Tags: c++, arduino

realice un reloj de 24 horas con Arduino, el cual se muestra en una LCD, con el siguiente formato: 00:00:00, donde comenzado por la izquierda tendremos las horas, luego los minutos y finalmente los segundos. El código principal se encuentra en el loop principal donde rústicamente un contador incrementa cada segundo tras cada interacción. Ahora adicionalmente para setear valores en el reloj en los minutos y horas estoy usando 2 pulsadores, pero es requerimiento usar interrupciones para este caso. Las interrupciones las he implementado en los botones pero ahora tengo el siguiente problema:

La interrupción funciona y cada vez que presiono uno de los botones correspondiente a minutos u horas se ejecuta una subrutina donde hace el incremento, pero tras un numero determinado de pulsaciones la interrupción deja de ser efectiva y los valores ya no incrementan presionado el pulsador.

Este es mi código, espero haber sido claro:

```
LiquidCrystal lcd(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11);
int su=0;
int sd=0;
volatile int mu=0;
volatile int md=0;
volatile int hu=0;
volatile int hd=0;
int pm=2;
int ph=3;
const int timeThreshold = 150;
long startTime = 0;





void setup() {
 lcd.begin(16,2);
 pinMode(pm, INPUT);
 pinMode(ph, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pm),handleInterrupt,FALLING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(ph),handleInterrupt1,FALLING);



 
}

void loop() {
    su++;
    delay(1000);
    lcd.setCursor(8,0);
    lcd.print(su);
    lcd.setCursor(7,0);
    lcd.print(sd);

  if(su==10)
  {
    su=0;
    sd++;
    lcd.clear();
  }
  if(sd==6 && su==0)
  {
    su=0;
    sd=0;
    mu++;
    lcd.clear();

  }
  if(mu==10)
  {
    mu=0;
    md++;
    lcd.clear();

  }
  if(md==6 && mu==0)
  {
    md=0;
    mu=0;
    hu++;
    lcd.clear();
  }
  if(hu==10)
  {
    hu=0;
    hd++;
    lcd.clear();
  }
  if(hd==2 && hu==4)
  {
    hd=0;
    hu=0;
    md=0;
    mu=0;
    sd=0;
    su=0;
    lcd.clear();
  }

    lcd.setCursor(1,0);
    lcd.print(hd);
    lcd.setCursor(2,0);
    lcd.print(hu);
    lcd.setCursor(3,0);
    lcd.print(":");

    lcd.setCursor(4,0);
    lcd.print(md);
    lcd.setCursor(5,0);
    lcd.print(mu);
    lcd.setCursor(6,0);
    lcd.print(":");

    lcd.setCursor(7,0);
    lcd.print(sd);
    lcd.setCursor(8,0);
    lcd.print(su);

}

void handleInterrupt(){
     if (millis() - startTime > timeThreshold)
  {
    mu++;
    startTime = millis();
  }


}

void handleInterrupt1(){
   if (millis() - startTime > timeThreshold)
  {
    hu++;
    startTime = millis();
  }

}
```